# How to find place in binary code where certain string is used

Tags: executable, machine-code

I am trying to analyze a binary executable file. I want to find the location of a certain function in this file; I happen to know that this function uses a specific string literal. I have found the location of this string in the binary code; I decided to search in the file for its address, hoping to catch the instruction that refers to this string, but I couldn't find anything. I assumed that this is because the position of data within the binary code is different from the actual address of the data when the code is being executed.

To test this, I compiled and executed a test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char* s1 = "ABCDEF\n";

int main(void) {
    const char* s2 = "123456\n";
    printf("%p %p", s1, s2);
}
```

Sure enough, the program prints "404000 404008", while the positions of the two strings in the binary code are 0x2400 and 0x2408, respectively.

How should I proceed in this situation?

I am running a Windows, 64-bit, AMD architecture. I am not opposed to downloading new software for this task, as long as it is free (I already have a decent hex editor.)

Comment: Did you take the virtual position of the data section into account?

Comment: I'm not entirely certain what the virtual position is, actually. Sorry, I'm much more of a higher-level programmer that has just started dabbling in memory hacking.